# P-value from Chi sq test statistic in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, chi-squared

I have computed a test statistic that is distributed as a chi square with 1 degree of freedom, and want to find out what P-value this corresponds to using python.

I'm a python and maths/stats newbie so I think what I want here is the probability denisty function for the chi2 distribution from SciPy. However, when I use this like so:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.chi2.pdf(3.84 , 1)
0.029846
```

However some googling and talking to some colleagues who know maths but not python have said it should be 0.05.

Any ideas?
Cheers,
Davy

Comment: If you run the test using [`scipy.stats.chisquare`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare.html), do you get the desired result?

Comment: Btw., when I compute the PDF according to the Wikipedia I get the same result as SciPy: `x = 3.84; reciprocal(2**.5 * gamma(.5)) * x ** (.5 - 1) * exp(- x / 2)`

Comment: I think you're using the wrong function . . . as @larsmans mentions, you should probably use the chisquare function, but make sure to pass it array of the actual and expected, and it'll return to you both the 3.84 and the p-valu you're looking for.

Comment: The reason I haven't done this to start with is that I don't have arrays of actual and expected. This is a novel analysis developed by a colleague. It follows a chi-sq distribution but is not a classical chi-sq contingency table test. So I don't think I can use this. I need to be able to derive a p-value from the test-statistic alone.

Comment: Ah, so how about pval = 1 - stats.chi2.cdf(3.84, 1) (saw this over in [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/446241-chi-squared-tests-python).

Comment: or even better >>> stats.chi2.sf(3.84, 1)
0.050043521248705106  for some gains in precision in the tail

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Quick refresher here:

Probability Density Function: think of it as a point value; how dense is the probability at a given point?

Cumulative Distribution Function: this is the mass of probability of the function up to a given point; what percentage of the distribution lies on one side of this point?

In your case, you took the PDF, for which you got the correct answer.  If you try 1 - CDF:

```
>>> 1 - stats.chi2.cdf(3.84, 1)
0.050043521248705147
```

[PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)
[CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)

Comment: That does not really answer the question, as you assumed that op was interested in right sided configuration for p-value.

Answer (score 26):

To calculate probability of null hypothesis given chisquared sum, and degrees of freedom you can also call `chisqprob`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import chisqprob
>>> chisqprob(3.84, 1)
0.050043521248705189
```

---

**Notice:**

> [chisqprob](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisqprob.html) is deprecated! stats.chisqprob is deprecated in scipy 0.17.0; use [stats.distributions.chi2.sf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html) instead

Comment: Thanks for the note about chi2.sf()

Answer (score 26):

Update: as noted, chisqprob() is deprecated for scipy version 0.17.0 onwards. High accuracy chi-square values can now be obtained via scipy.stats.distributions.chi2.sf(), for example:

```
>>>from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
>>>chi2.sf(3.84,1)
0.050043521248705189
>>>chi2.sf(1424,1)
1.2799986253099803e-311
```

---

While stats.chisqprob() and 1-stats.chi2.cdf() appear comparable for small chi-square values, for large chi-square values the former is preferable. The latter cannot provide a p-value smaller than machine epsilon,and will give very inaccurate answers close to machine epsilon. As shown by others, comparable values result for small chi-squared values with the two methods:

```
>>>from scipy.stats import chisqprob, chi2
>>>chisqprob(3.84,1)
0.050043521248705189
>>>1 - chi2.cdf(3.84,1)
0.050043521248705147
```

Using 1-chi2.cdf() breaks down here:

```
>>>1 - chi2.cdf(67,1)
2.2204460492503131e-16
>>>1 - chi2.cdf(68,1)
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>>1 - chi2.cdf(69,1)
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>>1 - chi2.cdf(70,1)
0.0
```

Whereas chisqprob() gives you accurate results for a much larger range of chi-square values, producing p-values nearly as small as the smallest float greater than zero, until it too underflows:

```
>>>chisqprob(67,1)
2.7150713219425247e-16
>>>chisqprob(68,1)
1.6349553217245471e-16
>>>chisqprob(69,1)
9.8463440314253303e-17    
>>>chisqprob(70,1)
5.9304458500824782e-17
>>>chisqprob(500,1)
9.505397766554137e-111
>>>chisqprob(1000,1)
1.7958327848007363e-219
>>>chisqprob(1424,1)
1.2799986253099803e-311
>>>chisqprob(1425,1)
0.0
```

Comment: A very nice answer :)

Comment: A quick note: `chisqprob` is deprecated, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisqprob.html#scipy.stats.chisqprob

Comment: Thanks @cqcn1991 -- I added an update to the solution.

Answer (score 7):

You meant to do:

```
>>> 1 - stats.chi2.cdf(3.84, 1)
0.050043521248705147
```

Answer (score 5):

Some of the other solutions are deprecated. Use `scipy.stats.chi2` Survival Function. Which is the same as `1 - cdf(chi_statistic, df)`

Example:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2
p_value = chi2.sf(chi_statistic, df)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to understand the math, the p-value of a sample, x (fixed), is

P[P(X) <= P(x)] = P[m(X) >= m(x)]  = 1 - G(m(x)^2)

where,

- P is the probability of a (say k-variate) normal distribution w/ known covariance (cov) and mean,
- X is a random variable from that normal distribution,
- m(x) is the mahalanobis distance = sqrt( < cov^{-1} (x-mean), x-mean >. Note that in 1-d this is just the absolute value of the z-score.
- G is the CDF of the chi^2 distribution w/ k degrees of freedom.

So if you're computing the p-value of a fixed observation, x, then you compute m(x) (generalized z-score), and 1-G(m(x)^2).

for example, it's well known that if x is sampled from a univariate (k = 1) normal distribution and has z-score = 2 (it's 2 standard deviations from the mean), then the p-value is about .046 (see a z-score table)

```
In [7]: from scipy.stats import chi2

In [8]: k = 1

In [9]: z = 2

In [10]: 1-chi2.cdf(z**2, k)
Out[10]: 0.045500263896358528
```

Answer (score 2):

For ultra-high precision, when scipy's `chi2.sf()` isn't enough, bring out the big guns:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from rpy2.robjects import r
>>> np.exp(np.longdouble(r.pchisq(19000, 2, lower_tail=False, log_p=True)[0]))
1.5937563168532229629e-4126
```

*Update by another user (WestCoastProjects)*  When using the values from the OP we get:

```
np.exp(np.longdouble(r.pchisq(3.84,1, lower_tail=False, log_p=True)[0]))
Out[5]: 0.050043521248705198928
```

So there's that *0.05* you were looking for.

Comment: Yes `R` is the big guns for stats

Comment: but isn't the p-value P(chisquared >= x) and not P(chisquared > x)?