# Is there a python equivalent of R's qchisq function?

Tags: python, r, statistics, scipy, chi-squared

The R `qchisq` function converts a p-value and number of degrees of freedom to the corresponding chi-squared value.  Is there a Python library that has an equivalent?

I've looked around in SciPy without finding anything.

Comment: @mnel: That question relates to calculating the p-value from the chi squared value.  I'm trying to go in the other direction.

Comment: indeed. Close-vote retracted (should read more carefully!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725115/p-value-from-chi-sq-test-statistic-in-python

Comment: @Dwin: That question relates to calculating the p-value from the chi squared value. I'm trying to go in the other direction.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's `scipy.stats.chi2.ppf` - Percent point function (inverse of cdf).
E.g., in R:

```
> qchisq(0.05,5)
[1] 1.145476
```

in Python:

```
In [8]: scipy.stats.chi2.ppf(0.05, 5)
Out[8]: 1.1454762260617695
```

Answer (score 3):

As @VadimKhotilovich points out in his answer, you can use `scipy.stats.chi2.ppf`. You can also use the function `chdtri` from `scipy.special`, but use 1-p as the argument.

R:

```
> qchisq(0.01, 7)
[1] 1.239042
> qchisq(0.05, 7)
[1] 2.16735
```

scipy:

```
In [16]: from scipy.special import chdtri

In [17]: chdtri(7, 1 - 0.01)
Out[17]: 1.2390423055679316

In [18]: chdtri(7, 1 - 0.05)
Out[18]: 2.1673499092980579
```

The only advantage to use `chdtri` over `scipy.stats.chi2.ppf` is that it is *much* faster:

```
In [30]: from scipy.stats import chi2

In [31]: %timeit chi2.ppf(0.05, 7)
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 us per loop

In [32]: %timeit chdtri(7, 1 - 0.05)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.67 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in ***R***

> qchisq(0.05, 9, **lower.tail=FALSE**)

in ***Python***
would be

> chi2.ppf(q= 0.95, df = 9) *#q = (1-0.05)*