# Testing equivalents to R pchisq in Python

Tags: python, r, chi-squared

Is there a equivalent of pchisq R command in Python. As was said [in this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070299/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-rs-qchisq-function), I were using chi2.ppf from scipy but I am not getting the same results as in R. For example, the following code:

**R:**

```
pchisq(38972.27814544528, df = 1)
Out: 1

pchisq(40569.99000034796, df = 1)
Out: 1
```

**Python:**

```
chi2.ppf(38972.27814544528, df = 1)
Out: NaN

chi2.ppf(40569.99000034796, df = 1)
Out: NaN
```

Thaks in advance for the help.

Comment: in the question you cited, they are using `qchisq`, not `pchisq`, the answer by peacewang is correct. note the chisq value you are testing, is really huge

Comment: @StupidWolf That's right. Thanks for pointing me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stats.chi2.cdf` in Python:

```
stats.chi2.cdf(38972.27814544528,df=1)
# 1.0
```

Comment: This link is useful: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_Calcul_P_Value.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your help